# how to change the color mapping for legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

We ploted the point,smooth line and text in one page with same color mapping, we only want to select one (e.g. geom_point) in legend,how to change the legend.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
data(mtcars)
df <- mtcars
df$cyl <- as.factor(df$cyl)

cor.test(df$mpg,df$wt)
b <- ggplot(df, aes(x = wt, y = mpg))
b + geom_point(aes(color = cyl))+
  geom_smooth(aes(color = cyl), method = lm,se = FALSE, fullrange = TRUE)+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"))+
  ggpubr::stat_cor(aes(color = cyl), method='pearson',label.x = 2.4,
                   r.digits = 3,p.digits = 4)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(family="Times",size=10),
        axis.text = element_text(family="Times",color="black",size=8),
        legend.title = element_text(family="HST",face="bold",size=8),
        legend.text=element_blank(),
        legend.key.size = unit(0.3,'cm'),
        legend.position = "top",
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `show.legend = FALSE` on the layers you don't want to show in the legend.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
data(mtcars)
df <- mtcars
df$cyl <- as.factor(df$cyl)

ggplot(df, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = cyl))+
  geom_smooth(aes(color = cyl), method = lm,se = FALSE, fullrange = TRUE, 
              show.legend = FALSE)+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"))+
  ggpubr::stat_cor(aes(color = cyl), method='pearson',label.x = 2.4,
                   r.digits = 3,p.digits = 4, show.legend = FALSE)
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>